# Command prompt window priority on Windows Server 2008 R2 (Windows 7)

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, sleep, thread-priority

Is an application running in a console window treated "less important" by the windows scheduler, i.e. does Windows allow it to "sleep" longer if it's minimized? I thought I read something about Windows lowering its priority if it's minimized, but perhaps I just mixed something up.

The thing is, I have a C console app (written in VS2015, but running on Windows Server 2008 R2, so no `GetSystemTimePrecise` support, unfortunately), which does some socket communication, but sometimes the receiving threads (IOCP) get paused and packets get merged together.

So, in my main function I wrote something like this:

```
 timeBeginPeriod(1);

while (true)
{
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
    Sleep(1);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&stop);
    LogTimeElapsed(start, stop);
}
```

I obviously didn't expect to get millisecond accuracy out of `Sleep(1)`, but I was surprised to get numerous delays of ~50 milliseconds, with maximum reaching **more than 120 milliseconds** on several occasions.

Of course, during this time, there were other active processes consuming CPU (doing some database exporting and similar, with total CPU going to ~50%), but since this is a quad core CPU I thought that the thread scheduler would still prevent such long delays from happening.

Is this an artifact of running as a plain console app, or should I expect similar delays in any Windows desktop/service application?

Comment: The answer depends on what was running on the server, but in general you can't expect much accuracy from the sleep function and should design your code around this. If you need more accuracy, maybe you need something like a timer.

Comment: This has a smell of XY about it.  With TCP, 'packets get merged together' by design.  With UDP, packets get merged together by bug.  Still, given your little loop, I am surprised that you ever get that much delay with a lightly-loaded quad-core box.  Sleep(1) may as well be Sleep(0), and is essentially a reschedule kernel call.

Comment: Hmm..., what do you mean exactly by *the receiving threads (IOCP) get paused and **packets get merged together**?* Could you be speaking of re-arranging of TCP packets?

Comment: @this.lau_: the point of the code was to check where the delays were coming from, because I didn't see any reason to some of the delays I detected in the other part of the app.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit: I understand what you're saying, but here is the problem: the packets are being sent by a device on the same switch every 20ms, and I can see them in Wireshark running on this same machine, i.e. for each TCP packet, the time packet was received matches the time reported by the sensor, with a (say) 5ms delay (both server and sensor are time-synchronized). But I see that my test console app gets these delays, right after which the next recv call gets merged packets.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit: however, I am not sure if it's "lightly-loaded", there *are* some services running which sometimes consume as much as 50% CPU during several seconds, but still.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: the packets are received and acknowledged in sequence, I see no retransmissions in Wireshark. Basicaly the TCP part of my question is not so relevant to my actual question (large `sleep(1)` delays), I just wanted to provide some background.

Comment: Well, what happens if you raise the priority of your network process?

Comment: 'packets are being sent by a device on the same switch every 20ms' - is nagle turned off at the device?

Comment: In nay case, if using TCP, you must not try and depend upon timing to identify messages longer than one byte.  It will not work reliably, (see Serge answer).

Comment: Also note that expiry of a Sleep() interval is not equivalent to the signaling of readiness of a network buffer.  When a thread becomes ready upon signaling of a synchro object, (eg. when an IOCP port completion message.becomes available), it applies a temporary priority boost to improve the chances of that thread becoming running 'immediately'.  Sleep() expiry does not result in a priority boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows is not a real time system, so it is allowed to suspend a task for a non deterministic time. If other tasks use the 4 cores during a short time (some tenths of seconds) any program (be it console of GUI) can be suspended for that time. And as Windows is a feature rich OS, many system services can compete for the CPU in addition to other tasks, so latencies up to few tenths of seconds can be expected at any time

Simply the TCP stack guarantees that the program will get all the data received during that time in correct order, but it is allowed to concatenate several packets in on single read because TCP is a stream protocol. So you program should be prepared for that. The only alternative is to use a real time OS, either on the main machine or on a dedicated one.

Comment: Indeed.  If only a small amount of data is received on the network, the stack might defer signaling it for a while in the 'hope' of receiving more data and so returning a fuller buffer, (similar to nagle, but at rx end).